# Is there a way to create custom reports in Confluence?

Tags: confluence

My company uses Confluence as a sort of knowledge base. I am a user of the system but not an administrator. We try to encourage people to make entries in Confluence often, to share what they know with everyone.

I received a question from a manager today, asking if there is some way to create  a search once and then run it whenever she needs, like a report. She wants the search results to show a list of users and the number of contributions they've made in the defined time periods.

For example:

```
User             # of contribs this week                 # of contribs this month
A Able           0                                       0
B Brown          10                                      33
J Smith          11                                      22
```

Is any of that possible within Confluence itself? (we're not currently doing any development using the APIs, for instance) I've searched online and not found anything yet.